# Ways to troubleshoot a connection (works for some, doesn't work for others)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, heroku, dns

I've got a site that's currently in beta and thus password-protected (sorry, can't show yet). Most of my users access the site no problem and able to interact with it, upload files, ..etc. There's one guy, however, who seems to have a persisten issue with access. Whenever he accesses the site, the connection times out and Heroku sends back an app-not-available response. Better yet, that screws access to everyone else at that time and I have to wait for the service to restart. Heroku logs show no sign of any issues. New Relic logs are also fine.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could troubleshoot , what tools I could use to monitor?

Comment: Have you contacted Heroku support? They're probably best positioned to help.

Comment: Their support responds with "hm.. we can't see anything in the logs. sorry, good luck" - seriously.

Comment: Do the NewRelic logs show any queuing at all?  Assuming the response is a 503 Service Unavailable, if you have a free Heroku instance (ie one process) and *any* request takes more than the Heroku timeout (I think 20-30 seconds) everyone else will get the 503.

Comment: @TomLianza thanks. That is indeed true, but I've got hirefire set up to autoscale Heroku whenever requests take more than 700ms, which means I should be okay most of the time. Seriously, it's just like this one person who is having cluster-nutting issues ;)

Comment: After the person accesses the site, and it goes down for everyone, do you see errors in NewRelic then?  Or Heroku?  If the site is down for everyone and you're not able to see any errors, that should be a straightforward support case.  Perhaps you can back into the root cause from there.

In the case of Heroku, NewRelic is *the* provided way to monitor your apps, aside from the limited log access they give you.  So, although NewRelic is a different company, Heroku does assume ownership of your ability to monitor your own app and will help you if NewRelic doesn't show data.

Comment: According to ZerigoDNS my dns routing was set incorrectly and after changing the settings all should work fine. I am going to wait for that user to come back to the site and see if it crashes again. Stay tuned! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have also had issues like this with heroku from time to time, and they have blamed in on EC2 when I contacted them. However, this has only happened to me twice and hasn't happened in months.

I tweeted @heroku and @salesforce with the problem when I got a snarky remark, and it got me in touch with someone who was actually able to help me. Sometimes they can be quite standoffish :)

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't help to solve the problem, but at least gives me hope that someone somewhere might fix this.